# How to eliminate repeated rows from table with composite primary key ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, row

I need to find the repeated rows from a table where the first three columns will make up the primary key.  Then after finding out which one's are repeated, those repeated rows need to be removed from the query results as this example shows:
Given this table.  The first 3 columns act as the primary key.

--------------1 2 3 4 5 6-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------1 2 3 9 8 9-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------1 4 3 9 8 9-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------3 4 2 2 2 1-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------2 3 4 1 1 3-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------2 3 4 9 9 0--------

Since 1 2 3 is the composite primary key. The first 2 rows should be considered repeated and therefore eliminated from the results. Just as the two 2 3 4 rows.
The only rows in the result set should be:

1 4 3 9 8 9 and 3 4 2 2 2 1

Could you please help?

Thanks a lot in advance..

Comment: If you declare columns as a composite primary key, then Oracle would not allow duplicates to be inserted.

Comment: I am guessing the OP wants to crate a composite primary key, but cannot because of the duplication

Comment: You are right, it is NOT declared as composite primary key.. we just use it "AS IF" it was.. but it's not declared.

Comment: Please format your sample data properly.

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't fully make sense.  A composite primary key would prevent duplicates in the table.  So, these columns are *not* declared as a comosite primary key if the data contains duplicates.

If you just one one row for each group, you can use `row_number()` for this, something like this (the column names are obviously invalid):

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by 1, 2, 3 order by 1) as seqnum
      from table t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

If you want to delete extra rows, you can try:

```
delete from t
    where rowid not in (select min(rowid) from table t group by 1, 2, 3);
```

EDIT:

If you want to remove cases where the rows are repeated, then you want `count()` instead of `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, count() over (partition by 1, 2, 3) as cnt
      from table t
     ) t
where cnt > 1;
```

Comment: Ok, It's not a primary key.. sorry for the confusion.. they are "used" as an informal identification for the row.. but they are NOT a primary key.  The rest is the same

Comment: I don't want 1 row for each group.  Each row that has a repeated and matching value on columns 1, 2 and 3 needs to be taken out of the results of the query.  Also, i do not need to delete rows from a table.. just from the results in the query.